# want install tigrinya/amharic est africa language on my 16.04 LTS UBUNTU version, help

Tags: software-installation

i would like to install tigrinya/amharic software in my ubuntu 16.04 LTS ubuntu, i'm fresh user of linux, can some one help

Answer (score 0):

**To install the Amharic language on Ubuntu 16.04:**

1. Open "System Settings"
2. Go to "Language Support"
3. Click "Install/Remove Languages"
4. Select Amharic
5. Click "Apply"
6. Under "Language for menus and windows", click and drag Amharic to the top of the list, if it is not already there

**If you want to apply this language for just the current user:**

1. Log out and log back in

**If you want to apply this language for the whole system and all users:**

1. Click "Apply System-Wide"
2. Reboot

Comment: thank you so much andrea..some one helped me to install amharic or ge'ez, the only thing i have to learn how and were i get big part of the alphabets, for instance the key-bord gives you "ha", but in ge'ez you have also "hu" "hi" "hie" "h" "ho" which i'm not able to find doing some combination of the key-board.

Comment: Glad I could help! Regarding typing, I'm really not sure how abugidas work on computer keyboards. You could maybe research Devanagari, Lao, Tamil, etc, and see if the methods are similar.